# Dropdown functionality of shinyWidgets::pickerInput inside bslib::page_navbar does not work

Tags: r, shiny, shinywidgets, bslib

I have a small reprex of this issue:

```
# R v4.2.3
# RStudio Pro v2023.06.0
library(shiny) # v1.7.2
library(bslib) # v0.5.0
library(shinyWidgets) # v0.7.6

page_navbar(
    header = pickerInput('pickId', choices = month.abb),
    title = 'reprex',
    nav('tab 1', 'content 1'),
    nav('tab 2', 'content 2')
)
```

The ui will appear fine, but the picker input is greyed out and the drop down will not pop up.

[image: screenshot of issue in reprex]

It also does not work if the pickerInput is placed somewhere else in the UI, for example:

```
page_navbar(
    title = 'reprex',
    nav_panel('tab 1', 'content 1'),
    nav_panel('tab 2', pickerInput('pickId', choices = month.abb))
)
```

Compare this to a similar example:

```
page_navbar(
    header = selectInput('selectId', 'label', choices = month.abb),
    title = 'reprex',
    nav_panel('tab 1', 'content 1'),
    nav_panel('tab 2', selectInput('selectId2', 'label', choices = month.abb))
)
```

Which works without issues.

Specifically what technical issue is causing this?
How can I make this work? The accepted answer MUST use pickerInput.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem may occur due to a compatibility issue between `pickerInput()` and `bslib` (see also [this](https://github.com/dreamRs/shinyWidgets/issues/535) open issue on GitHub).

However, what seems to let the `pickerInput()` work is switching to a theme which relies on another BootsTrap version.

```
library(shiny)
library(bslib)
library(shinyWidgets)

page_navbar(
    theme = bs_theme(version = 3, bootswatch = "default"),
    header = pickerInput('pickId', choices = month.abb),
    title = 'reprex',
    nav_panel('tab 1', 'content 1'),
    nav_panel('tab 2', 'content 2')
)
```

[image]